# How to install netbeans in redhat 7

Tags: java, netbeans, redhat, netbeans-8

I have installed redhat-7 on vmware . I can installed and access netbeans-8.1 in it using xen software . But When I  login via remote desktop I can't access it . The full window is shown as black page . Here is the screenshot .

[image]

I have logged in redhat server via remote desktop . I cant install netbeans in it . When I try to install redhat the above screen is shown .

I have installed eclipse  software in it . Eclipse runs in it very fine . The problem is solved if I use xencenter software . But I have to use redhat pc via remote desktop .

How can I solve this problem ? Please help me .

Comment: how did you install it? using yum? or you downloaded from netbeans?

Comment: I have downloaded netbeans.sh file from betneans.org website . Then I have run the installer using this command ./netbenas8.1.sh

Comment: there is a registered bug for this, try the solutions in the bottom of the page: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=244806 (1. change the skin to lighter one, 2. enable direct draw)

Comment: I have Modified the default options in netbeans.conf from:
 -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true
to:
 -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=false . But no change is detected .